# How can I make random platforms spawn from random points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry for the newbie question.

I want to spawn random platforms from one of five random spawn points. The platforms will float upwards and the player will jump on them.

For example, one platform has an enemy, one has a coin, one has a coin and an enemy, one is empty. There are five points from which a random platform may randomly spawn.

One iteration of my code could make the platforms spawn from random points, but it only worked with one platform. I haven't figured out how to add in multiple platforms and spawn them randomly.

```
public class RandomSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] points;
    public GameObject[] obstacles;
    public float invokeRate = 1.0f;
    public GameObject platform;

    int spawnNum = Random.Range(0, 5);
    int prefabNum = Random.Range(0, 3);

    private void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("AllSpawn", 1.0f, invokeRate);
    }

    void AllSpawn()
    {
        Instantiate(obstacles[prefabNum], points[spawnNum].position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

The code above just spawns one type of platform from one spot. i have added multiple platforms to the array but just the one spawns.

Comment: `int spawnNum = Random.Range(0, 5);` and `int prefabNum = Random.Range(0, 3);` are both initialized exactly once so they will always keep the same values.

Answer (score 1):

`int spawnNum = Random.Range(0, 5);` and `int prefabNum = Random.Range(0, 3);` are both initialized exactly once so they will always keep the same values and never change to a new random number.

I would recommend making this change:

```
private void AllSpawn() 
{
    Instantiate(
        obstacles[Random.Range(0, obstactles.Length)], 
        points[Random.Range(0, points.Length)].position, 
        Quaternion.identity
    );
}
```

Comment: I took the freedom to change the code slightly. Note that for the `int` overload the maximum parameter of [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) is **exclusive** so you don't have to do `-1` because the maximum returned value already will be e.g. `obstactles.Length -1`